# Django Template Complex Reverse Query Count

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have this model where a supervisor is a foreign key for a team, which is a foreign key for an individual employee.

model.py

```
class Supervisor(models.Model):
    [fields..]

class Team(models.Model):
    shift = ...
    department = ...
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(Supervisor, related_name="team_supervisor")

class Employee(models.Model):
    [fields...]
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="employee_team")
```

In using the Supervisor model in a view, and while looping through each supervisor I can list how many teams a supervisor manages with the statement:

```
{{ supervisor.team_supervisor.count }}
```

How can I show the total number of individual employees that work for a supervisor across every team that supervisor has? I assumed the follow would work but it does not:

```
{{ supervisor.team_supervisor.employee_team.count }}
```

Comment: Well, writing *supervisor.team_supervisor* you access an object responsible for all the teams, accessing *employee_team* will only be possible for one specific team

Comment: So then how can I subtotal across all teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to modify your queryset and annotate it using `Count` from the `django.db.models.aggregates` module ([docs & examples here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/)). Like so:

```
from django.db.models import Count
supervisors = Supervisor.objects.annotate(employee_count=Count('team__employee'))
```